# Transparent, publicly updatable accumulator with constant-sized witnesses

Tags: accumulators

I am looking for an accumulator with the following properties:

1. Transparent: No trusted setup (rules out RSA and pairing-based accumulators)
2. Publicly updatable: No central authority (rules out digital signatures)
3. Constant-sized witnesses: (rules out Merkle accumulator)

Are there accumulators with all the above properties?

The intended use case is a public blockchain without a "super user"/"admin"/"authority" managing the accumulator. In particular, witnesses should be publicly verifiable, accumulator updates (additions and/or deletions) should be public, and witnesses should be updatable from publicly broadcasted auxiliary information.

Comment: Regarding 1) Actually, that does not rule out RSA. It's possible to generate an RSA key in a distributed fashion, where no single party holds the private key. Regarding 2), I think you need to be more specific, I am not sure what you actually mean.

Comment: Regarding 1), would you mind linking to a paper of the distributed construction?

Comment: *Efficient Generation of Shared RSA key* by Boneh and Franklin (1997, although google scholar shows it with 2001),  *Robust efficient distributed RSA-key generation* by Frankel, MacKenzie and Yung (1998).

Comment: _Constant-sized witnesses_ is going to limit what can be accumulated, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

**Later edit:** Actually, some [new Stanford work](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/1188) shows how to obtain transparent RSA accumulators using *class groups*. This was also discussed in [Secure Accumulators from Euclidean Rings without Trusted Setup](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-31284-7_14), by Helger Lipmaa.

The Stanford work also shows how to publicly add and remove elements in the accumulator. And the proofs are constant-sized.

**Original answer:** If you're willing to generate RSA keys in a distributed fashion, then you might as well go for [bilinear accumulators](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/123.pdf), since you can also generate $q$-SDH parameters for them in a distributed fashion and they will be faster for non-membership proofs and also support subset proofs.

Depending on how you squint your eyes, **yes**, bilinear accumulators have all of those properties.

1. **No trusted setup:** just use MPC to generate $q$-SDH public parameters.
2. **Publicly updatable:** given old set $X$ and updates $U$ s.t. new set $X' = X \cup U$, anybody can simply recompute $acc(X')$.
3. **Constant-sized witnesses:** bilinear accumulator witnesses are 1 group element for membership and 1 group element plus 1 field element for non-membership.
4. **Witnesses should be publicly-verifiable:** in bilinear accumulator they are
5. **Accumulator updates (additions and/or deletions) should be public(ly made)**: anybody can recompute an updated bilinear accumulator
6. **Witnesses should be updatable from publicly-broadcasted auxiliary information**: I know membership witnesses can be easily updated in $O(1)$ time after 1 addition to the accumulator. Not sure about non-membership witnesses. However, given the new set $X'$, anybody can compute a new witness in $O(n)$ time.

Hope this helps!